# What is the meaning of “down to the fact”?

Tags: meaning, expressions, phrase-requests, idioms, idiom-meaning

What does it mean in this sentence?

> This comes *down to the fact* that boys like toys.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant phrase isn't "down to the fact" but "come down to".

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come%20down%20to) has

> **come down to**
> to have (something) as the most important part
>
> *People talk about various reasons for the company's failure, but it all comes down to one thing: a lack of leadership.*
> *The election is going to come down to which candidate seems most trustworthy to the voters.*

So your sentence

> This comes down to the fact that boys like toys.

means

> The reason is that boys like toys.
> This is all about boys liking toys.

etc. depending on the full context.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that the most common verb for the usage is in fact TO BE. As in ***It's** [all] down to [some fact]*, rather than *It **comes** down to [whatever]*.